# How can i get my object id from a generic update views to use in my form in django 1.1

Tags: django, django-generic-views, object-identity

I m using generic view to update object.

I m using form :

```
class VehiPrepaClientForm(ModelForm):




class Meta:
    model = VehiPrepa
    fields = ('date_dem_prepa','carburant','ty_carburant')



def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    data = self.cleaned_data['date_dem_prepa']

    vehiprepa = get_object_or_404(VehiPrepa,pk=object_id)
    if data :

        vehiprepa.demande_prepa = 1
        vehiprepa.save()
        date_in = vehiprepa.date_in
        delta = data - date_in
        date_dem = date_in + delta 
        if delta.days < 2 :
            raise forms.ValidationError("Veuillez entrez une date au dela du : %s" %(date_dem) )

        if data.weekday()>= 5 :

            raise forms.ValidationError("La date choisie n'est pas valide, cela tombe un weekend")    

        #test si date demande sup a date_in et si pas samedi, ni dimanche, et si pas plus 32 vehi ce jour la



    return cleaned_data
```

I m using this generic view :

```
def vehiprepa_update (request, vehiprepa_id):

user= request.user

login = user.username
vehiprepa = get_object_or_404(VehiPrepa,pk=vehiprepa_id)

url_template_base = "base_client_washtest.html"


    response = create_update.update_object(
            request,
            form_class = VehiPrepaClientForm, 
            object_id = vehiprepa_id,
            post_save_redirect = "/washtest/vehiprepa_list/0/",
            template_name = 'washtest/vehiprepa_update.html',
            template_object_name = 'object',
            extra_context = {"url_template_base":url_template_base,"login":login,"vehiprepa":vehiprepa},)

return response
```

But i have an error, because object_id on my form is not known....
How can i get my request object id to use in my form clean ?

Thx

EDIT : HEre the error :

> global name 'object_id' is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error comes from this line:

`vehiprepa = get_object_or_404(VehiPrepa,pk=object_id)`

In your model form, you don't have a `object_id`.

To solve this problem, refer to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method); which states:

> Also, a model form instance bound to a model object will contain a
>   self.instance attribute that gives model form methods access to that
>   specific model instance.

From that we understand that the bound instance is in `self.instance`. So, in your model form you need

`vehiprepa = self.instance`

instead of the `get_object_or_404` line.

Comment: Thx a lot... it'w works... i forget to look at this page.. thx from France ;)